# Difference between old Enterprise Library and new Process Modeling Library in AnyLogic 7

Tags: simulation, discrete-mathematics, anylogic

I don't know what is new and I don't know when to use which libary. Why is the Enterprise one old and should I still use it? Can someone help me out?

[image: Old]
[image: New]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Process Modeling Library is the new version of Enterprise Library. It has been included since AnyLogic 7. It supports pull protocol instead of push by default, it works with new space markup elements and can accept Agents as entities. 
Enterprise Library is still in AnyLogic just for compatibility. By default it is hidden. AnyLogic 7 users should work with Process Modeling Libray. More information about new library is available in Help: http://www.anylogic.com/anylogic/help/topic/com.xj.anylogic.help/html/_ELR/PML.html

Comment: There is also loads of information about the Process Modeling library in the material circulated with the free AnyLogic 7 training that has been run in several countries. @Pavel: is this material not being made public, even though the training was free? What is AnyLogic's stance on users sharing this material?